# getting error while navigating jquery tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

While fetching Node value of a tree, when I am clicking on submenu, though its getting placed inside input field txt, there is am error.... The error says

> Message: 'target.childNodes.0.nodeValue' is null or not an object
>   Line: 9
>   Char: 3
>   Code: 0

Any help??? thanks..

HTML

```
<ul id="browser" class="filetree">
    <li><span class="folder">Souvik_Workspace</span>
        <ul>
            <li><span class="file">Item 1.1</span></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span class="folder">Folder 2</span>
        <ul>
            <li><span class="folder">Subfolder 2.1</span>
                <ul id="folder21">
                    <li><span class="file">File 2.1.2</span></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="closed"><span class="folder">Folder 3 (closed at start)</span>
        <ul>
            <li><span class="file">File 3.1</span></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span class="file">File 4</span></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$("#browser >li").click(function(clk){
    var $val = clk.target.childNodes[0].nodeValue
    $("#workspace").attr('value',$val);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the "$" on `$val` variable !

jsfiddle and chrome developer tools are good way to debug simple code..
http://jsfiddle.net/bouillard/PUjHf/

Comment: That's not the problem, a variable can start with `$`.

Comment: OK... sorry... Then try to debug with chrome and developer tools !